# Call procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table , that store friendship like :

```
Friend : f_id , f_userid1 , f_userid2 , f_status .
```

If user a is friend with user b , I only insert one row :

```
 f_userid1 = a  , f_userid2 = b
```

I want to check if I have this friendship row , change the status to zero , I have created a procedure for it :

```
    BEGIN                                      
        DECLARE fid INT(15);

        -- check for first one 
        SELECT f_id INTO fid FROM f WHERE
        f_userid1 = @userid1
        AND f_userid2 = @userid2;

SET oup = 1;

        IF(fid = 0) THEN

SET oup = 2;
            -- check for SECOUND one 
            SELECT f_id INTO fid FROM f WHERE f_userid2 = @userid1 AND f_userid1 = @userid2;

        END IF;

            -- if statment


        IF(fid > 0) THEN

SET oup = 3;
            -- we need to update the exiting request
            UPDATE f SET f_userid1 = @userid1 , f_userid2 = @userid2 , f_status = 0 WHERE f_id = @fid ;

        END IF;

    END
```

I have a row like here before

```
f_id = 1 , f_userid1 = a . f_userid2 = b , f_status = 1;
```

It runs successfully , but no row affacted !

**I have added output and It only return 1 ;**

where is my problem ?

Comment: have you got any return? get a return type. Search for return types of store procedures

Comment: it only says 0 (zero ) row affacted .

Comment: @polin : I have added output and It only return 1 ;

Comment: Has it updated the values you want to update? Because as far as I am concerned, when you use return in SP, it returns 0 when successful, returns 1 when "Required parameter value is not specified".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not write it in a single query?

```
UPDATE f
SET f_status = 0
WHERE ( f_userid1 = @userid1 AND f_userid2 = @userid2 )
   OR ( f_userid1 = @userid2 AND f_userid2 = @userid1 );
```

Comment: That code do not work ! it gets problem in WHERE ( f_userid1 = XXX AND f_userid2 = XXX )
   OR ( f_userid1 = XXX AND f_userid2 = XXX )